# Find obsolete CSS selectors by comparing .css files with selectors that affect / render in DOM?

Tags: css, optimization, css-selectors

I want to get all CSS selectors that come within all CSS files (in most cases, included in HTML's head) and are possibly used in Javascript scripts (be it jQuery methods - addClass, removeClass, or vanilla JS - classList.add / classList.remove + other cases I didn't mention).

Then get all selectors that affect the DOM - but before, I simulate all possible cases of interaction with the website (clicks, hover, etc.) to determine the selectors used by scripts / for events.

Then compare the two and find obsolete CSS selectors for optimization of a website.

Is that possible? I can imagine the process of how it'd work, but it'd take some time develop a system of my own, thus, I'm looking for capable solutions online.

Comment: I'm absolutely certain this is an exact duplicate. Unfortunately there are many near-duplicates on this site and I can't seem to find the correct one. Hm.

Comment: Made a search myself before posting - no duplicates found. But feel free to point me out to a duplicate that offers a solution.